# How to check is device on given port is working

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have to write a code that is reading some information from serial port in endless loop, but I want to this script will be resistant to power failure. I try to iterate for all available ports, but it takes too long, beacuse I need to read around 13 lines every second, and do something with them. What is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: Please define "resistant to power failure". Usually if the power fail any software will stop working together with the device it runs on.

Comment: Let's say if device will be turn off, and after couple seconds turn on.